# Random EOFError - cucumber, capybara and webkit/chrome/firefox on OSX Yosemite

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

At this point, I have tried many, many things in desperation after all other avenues have failed.

So far:

- Reinstalled OSX
- Reinstalled Brew
- Reinstalled RVM
- Deleted/regenerated the network plist files

I have a clean install of the above, yet they do not seem to have affected the random `EOFError`.  I get the error 80% of the time, and 20% of the time it works.  Another developer next to me has the same OSX Yosemite version, same setup, and never hits the EOFError (hence why I tried the drastic steps above to cure the environment).

Stack:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in transport_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `catch'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in `request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:97:in `block in request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:105:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:105:in `block in request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:137:in `start_with_connect_without_finish'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:104:in `request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1128:in `get'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/server.rb:56:in `block in responsive?'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/webmock-1.19.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
/Users/kross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/server.rb:56:in `responsive?'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/server.rb:66:in `boot'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/session.rb:66:in `initialize'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara.rb:248:in `new'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara.rb:248:in `current_session'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@af_core/gems/capybara-2.4.3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
```

**It does not matter if I use `:selenium` (firefox/chrome) or `:webkit` (or `:webkit_debug`)**

Given that the same exact codebase works on another developer's machine (same OSX version, same ruby version, same purchase dates, same upgrade path), I'm not sure what in the environment is affecting the result.  The initiating line for the stack is `visit '/'`, and it is the first `visit` of the `scenario`.  Even subsequent `visit` attempts in a `Scenario Outline` examples begin working (usually on the 3rd example).

When running under `:webkit`, I see these in the console:

```
1/20/15 3:49:57.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff805f09b0f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff805f09b0f0, region 0x7fff93a00000->0x7fff93c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 3:49:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff805b3d90f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff805b3d90f0, region 0x7fff93a00000->0x7fff93c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 3:49:58.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 60983] at virtual address 0x105c4c000, protections were read-write
1/20/15 3:50:23.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80677c4d20) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80677c4d20, region 0x7fff93a00000->0x7fff93c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 3:50:26.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff805b3d90f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff805b3d90f0, region 0x7fff93a00000->0x7fff93c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 3:50:26.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff805f09b0f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff805f09b0f0, region 0x7fff93a00000->0x7fff93c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 3:50:26.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 60987] at virtual address 0x109215000, protections were read-write
1/20/15 3:50:28.220 PM webkit_server[60988]: Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
1/20/15 3:50:28.237 PM webkit_server[60988]: objc[60988]: Class MacCocoaSocketServerHelperRtc is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

**Note:** I have tried to cleanup the plugins dir, and they keep coming back.  I do want to solve that annoyance, but at this point, it is just that and not a show stopper.

I was surprised to see references to `Google Chrome He` in the console when using the `:webkit` driver, because it should be utilizing `QT` 5.4.0 installed via `brew`.  These happened *even when chrome was not running*.

On a successful run, I see in the console:

```
1/20/15 3:59:33.285 PM WindowServer[131]: Surface testing disallowed updates for 10 sequential attempts...
1/20/15 3:59:33.290 PM WindowServer[131]: Surface test allowed updates after 10 attempts
1/20/15 3:59:40.286 PM webkit_server[61089]: Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
1/20/15 3:59:40.303 PM webkit_server[61089]: objc[61089]: Class MacCocoaSocketServerHelperRtc is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Any advice is welcome, all other avenues related to an `EOFError` haven't amounted to anything for me.

---

**Latest attempts**

1. make sure hostname is set

   `sudo scutil --set ComputerName "kross"`
   `sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "kross"`
   `sudo scutil --set HostName "kross"`

*No change*

2. Regarding `Data/Stack execution not permitted`, found [this reference](http://d43.me/blog/1370/fix-for-applications-crashing-on-startup-in-mountain-lion/):

   `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force`

and reboot.  *No change*

3. Delete Google Chrome, delete offending plugins, and reboot

***Works** (as far as I can tell)*

4. Reinstall Google Chrome
   *Test startup delay and EOFError failure*

Console:

```
1/20/15 4:33:02.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff802b8e9000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff802b8e9000, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:02.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd173c0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd173c0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:02.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 1509] at virtual address 0x105b5f000, protections were read-write
1/20/15 4:33:32.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd174b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd174b0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:33.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd172d0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd172d0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:33.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd171e0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd171e0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff802b8e9000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff802b8e9000, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8029eaa3c0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8029eaa3c0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:33:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 1516] at virtual address 0x105b4d000, protections were read-write
1/20/15 4:34:04.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd173c0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd173c0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:34:04.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd170f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd170f0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:34:04.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 1519] at virtual address 0x105c56000, protections were read-write
1/20/15 4:34:33.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd170f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd170f0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:34:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803bd171e0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803bd171e0, region 0x7fff94c00000->0x7fff94e00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
1/20/15 4:34:34.000 PM kernel[0]: Data/Stack execution not permitted: Google Chrome He[pid 1521] at virtual address 0x105d50000, protections were read-write
```

I'm confused as to the interplay of Google Chrome, when I expect with the `:webkit` driver that I'm using the `brew` installed `qt` 5.4.0.  What am I missing?

---

**ChromeDriver?**
Using `ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307)` circa 1/2014, it seems as soon as I pull it from the path, everything is better.  Note that since this problem is somewhat random, I can't be definitive with the result.  I'm updating to `ChromeDriver 2.13.307650` to see if it is better.  Please note again that I am not using selenium/chrome, but the webkit driver so I still don't know why this is affecting tests.  Even still, I'm not sure chrome has any relationship to the problem (though testing so far would imply otherwise).

---

***/Library/Internet Plug-Ins!!!!!***
This has to be the missing link.  There isn't any reason for `:webkit` to have any interplay with Google Chrome, yet still seeing occasional `EOFError`s and OSX console messages related to Google Chrome.  Part of this is because even though I've deleted files that are offending `QT` such as `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin`, they **keep coming back** when you restart chrome.  It doesn't matter that I've disabled them in `chrome://plugins`.  So, I really need a way to get `QT` to ignore them or *all* plugins in general.  [Related QT issue here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36349)

---

**Current workaround**

1. Open Chrome (leave open for your normal user browser)
2. Remove offending plugins

   `sudo rm '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/o1dbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/o1dbrowserplugin'` 
   `sudo rm '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin'`
3. Run your tests.

**IF YOU RESTART CHROME**, the plugins will be there again.  Rinse and repeat.

**Evidently**, if you don't restart chrome, they can still come back as well, just watch your log and rinse and repeat.

A resolution to this [related QT issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36349) would allow us to ignore plugins.